# Middleware is calling route twice while keeping record of accessing logs in db in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, kernel, middleware

I have created a middleware which checks each url and saves accessing logs data in database. Everything went fine but each time an url is loaded in the browser, the data is saved twice in the db. I am using laravel 8 and this project will be used for buying coupon from the shops by the users.

**App\Http\Middleware\AccessLog.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\LogRecord;
use Auth;

class AccessLog
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(strpos($request->path(), 'shop') !== false){
            $data['type'] = 'shop';// 'shop' or 'coupon' and for other type 'page' )
            $data['content'] = $request->route('id');//content -> shop.id or coupon.id. and other page is route path
        }
        elseif(strpos($request->path(), 'coupon') !== false){
            $data['type'] = 'coupon';
            $data['content'] = $request->route('id');
        }
        else{
            $data['type'] = 'page';
            $url_components = parse_url($request->path());
            $path =   explode('/',$url_components['path']);
            $data['content'] = $path[0];
        }

        $user = null;
        if (Auth::check()){
            $user = Auth::user()->id;
        } 
        $data['user_id'] = $user;
        $data['servicer_id'] = config('const.common.accesslog.servicer_id');
        $accesslog = LogRecord::create($data);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**App\Http\Kernel.php**

```
   protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'log' => \App\Http\Middleware\AccessLog::class,
    ];
```

**App\Models\LogRecord.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class LogRecord extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'access_logs';
    protected $fillable =['user_id','servicer_id','type','content'];
}
```

**database:**
[access_logs table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNsHK.png)

Each time the record is saved twice. What may be the problem?

Comment: Does this happen for every browser? I would try it with a clean browser (by clean i mean, for the most part, a browser without plugins installed).

Comment: I tried it in a incognito mode and it worked. So, why must it have been happened with my current working browser?

Comment: Most likely a browser plugin/extension. It happened to me before (don't remember which one it was though) that's why i asked you to verify that : )

Comment: But how can I make my browser work without incognito mode? Do you know any solution?

Comment: If the issue is a plugin the problem is not "it just works in incognito". You're dealing with a edge case where, apparently, users with a certain plugin will have that issue. If you want to deal with such a case i would inspect the `$request` object and look for identifying data that would allow me to filter these cases. Plugins usually send such data (such as an header, user-agent or things like that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/16174785/nitrin0
I got to know from nitrin0 that sometimes the plugin/extension may affect. So I tried disabling my each extension one by one. It worked after I disabled the following extension HTML 标签检测器|HTML TAG CHECKER from my google chrome browser. Quite unexpected!!
[extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tTJA.png)

Answer (score 0):

From your database screenshot, it seems that duplicate record is being added after some seconds ie. 2-3 seconds. So any other request ie. post or ajax is processed after page called. So please try below code for middleware **App\Http\Middleware\AccessLog.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\LogRecord;
use Auth;

class AccessLog
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->method()=='GET')
        {
            if(strpos($request->path(), 'shop') !== false){
            $data['type'] = 'shop';// 'shop' or 'coupon' and for other type 'page' )
            $data['content'] = $request->route('id');//content -> shop.id or coupon.id. and other page is route path
            }
            elseif(strpos($request->path(), 'coupon') !== false){
                $data['type'] = 'coupon';
                $data['content'] = $request->route('id');
            }
            else{
                $data['type'] = 'page';
                $url_components = parse_url($request->path());
                $path =   explode('/',$url_components['path']);
                $data['content'] = $path[0];
            }

            $user = null;
            if (Auth::check()){
                $user = Auth::user()->id;
            } 
            $data['user_id'] = $user;
            $data['servicer_id'] = config('const.common.accesslog.servicer_id');
            $accesslog = LogRecord::create($data);    
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. I cleared all browser cookies and cache also. But the  works fine in incognito mode .